# Is there a way to automatically delete auxiliary files after compilation?

Tags: auxiliary-files

When I compile my `.tex` file, it generates a lot of different files (with extensions such as `.aux`, `.log`), but all I want is the `.tex` and `.pdf` files. Those files just fill my hard drive for nothing. Is there any trick to make LaTeX retain only the `.pdf` and `.tex` files and delete everything else after compilation?

Comment: Latex needs those files.

Comment: LaTeX needs temporarily these files, in order to be able to make  a table of contents, a bibliography, cross references, etc. Usually, dedicated tex editors have a button to delete these file, when they aren't useful anymore. In the case of TeXmaker, the `Tools` menu has a `Clean`submenu.

Comment: Though the question was closed some technical advices: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. Also a suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @Bernard Does VScode have the similar *delete button* stuff? I can't find it.

Comment: @narip: Unfortunately, I don't use VScode, so I have no idea.